# Como recibo un form-data en un endpoint de mi API en ASP NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formdata

tengo un problema que no logro resolver. quiero recibir un content type: form-data en my api de C# en ASP NET ya que necesito mandar un PDF, pero, no logro recibirlo. con otros tipos de encriptacion recibo datos sin problemas, pero form-data no me deja.

mi endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/CartaPorte/sendFormData")]
public IActionResult sendPDF([FromForm] FormDataModel formData)
{
try
{
var ruta = formData.Ruta; 
var archivo = formData.PDFContent; 

   
return (IActionResult)BadRequest();
} catch (Exception Ex)
{

return (IActionResult)BadRequest();
}
}
```

mi modelo:

```
public class FormDataModel
{
public string Ruta { get; set; }
public List<IFormFile> PDFContent { get; set; }
}
```

Postman:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu código está bien, muestra el header del postman y el program.cs

Comment: ¿Que version de .NET estas utlizando? Porque en algunas versiones anteriores (NET Core X...) habia que "decorar" e indicar que se recibiria ""multipart/form-data". Y ademas tambien como te preguntasn seria bueno toda la config de header de Postman.

Comment: Efectivamente en .NET 7.0 esto funciona perfectamente. Indicanos que versión es para poder reproducir el problema

Answer (score 0):

espero te encuentres bien.

Por lo general este tipo de situaciones se presenta al definir el tipo de datos que va a enviar el form dentro de tu vista, te aconsejo revisar que el form en tu vista tenga el siguiente atributo

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Te dejo un link donde puedas ver poco más de [documentacion](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_form_enctype.asp) sobre el tema.

En caso de que el problema persista, agradezco nos puedas indicar la versión de .Net con la que estés trabajando para ayudarte.

Saludos.